# What UML Use Cases to Write?

Tags: uml, software-design, use-case

It's been a really long time since I worked with UML Diagrams.

I started working with UML Use Cases again, for a real world project. I would like to ask some questions.

How should I approach writing use cases?

I believe the tasks that leads to a "Major/Bigger" task should not be considered as use cases by themselves.  Am I right?

Okay, what if I have a task like `View tutorial` and it has `Comment on Tutorial`, `Favourite Tutorial`, etc. Should these be separate use case, `Extending View Tutorial`? If yes, but, aren't they small features, why we should include them?

I'm mixing some stuff here, I hope someone could enlighten me .

Thanks!

Comment: Can you detail better the complexity of each use case? How different is View Tutorial from Comment on Tutorial? Have you considered the general CRUD Tutorial use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Alistair Cockburn's Effective Use Cases book (see it on Amazon: [1](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Writing-Effective-Crystal-Software-Development/dp/0201702258)).  He does an excellent job of explaining practical use of use cases in a structured and effective way.